# logstash parse log field

Tags: regex, parsing, logstash, postfix-mta

I am trying to parse the `@message` field from a Postfix log and extract it into multiple fields.

**Message:**

```
<22>Sep 17 19:12:14 postfix/smtp[18852]: 28D40A036B: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=192.244.100.25[192.244.100.25]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0.09/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9030A15D0)
```

**LogStash Output:**

```
{
  "@source": "syslog://192.244.100.42/",
  "@tags": [
    "_grokparsefailure"
  ],
  "@fields": {
    "priority": 13,
    "severity": 5,
    "facility": 1,
    "facility_label": "user-level",
    "severity_label": "Notice"
  },
  "@timestamp": "2013-09-17T17:12:06.958Z",
  "@source_host": "192.244.100.42",
  "@source_path": "/",
  "@message": "<22>Sep 17 19:12:14 postfix/smtp[18852]: 28D40A036B: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=192.244.100.25[192.244.100.25]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0.09/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9030A15D0)",
  "@type": "syslog"
}
```

I've tried to use the grok parser but the data remains in the `@message` field. I want to use syslog parser with regular expressions.

What steps do I follow to parse the `@message` field?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a _grokparsefailure in your output indicates a problem parsing you logs. WHat is the grok filter you're using in your config?

Answer (score 0):

While we're now at Logstash 5.x, the concepts of grok remain the same.

Unfortunately Postfix has some really annoying patterns in logging, as in a handful of people have written some [patterns](https://github.com/whyscream/postfix-grok-patterns/blob/master/postfix.grok) that account for most of the data you'll end up seeing in Postfix logs. I will only use a few of them.

The key is to identify components of the message, if they conform to a standard or is largely popular it is likely a grok filter already has been written for it (e.g. syslog). Components of a message you do not know, you can write a filter for with grok.

Let's break the message into pieces:

- `<22>Sep 17 19:12:14 postfix/smtp[18852]:`: This is very nearly RFC5424 syslog, but it is missing the **ver (version)** field.

  - **SYSLOG5424PRI**: Priority value
  - **SYSLOGTIMESTAMP**: Self explanatory
  - **SYSLOGPROG**: The application's name
- `28D40A036B: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=192.244.100.25[192.244.100.25]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0.09/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9030A15D0)`: This is domain-specific information to Postfix.

  - **POSTFIX_KEYVALUE_DATA**: Used as a component of another filter to match key=value data (such as relay=..., delay=...).
  - **POSTFIX_QUEUEID**: Self explanatory
  - **POSTFIX_KEYVALUE**: Combines the POSTFIX_QUEUEID and POSTFIX_KEYVALUE_DATA.
  - **POSTFIX_SMTP_DELIVERY**: Uses POSTFIX_KEYVALUE to identify the above information until status=, after which is the SMTP response.

**Filter:**

```
filter {
    if [type] == "postfix" {
        grok {
            patterns_dir   => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
            match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{POSTFIX_SMTP_DELIVERY}" }
        }
    }
}
```

Where you would save the Postfix patterns in the patterns_dir.

**Output:**

```
{
    "postfix_queueid" => "28D40A036B",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-02-23T08:15:32.546Z,
    "postfix_smtp_response" => "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9030A15D0",
    "port" => 50228,
    "postfix_keyvalue_data" => "to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=192.244.100.25[192.244.100.25]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0.09/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent",
    "syslog5424_pri" => "22",
    "@version" => "1",
    "host" => "10.0.2.2",
    "pid" => "18852",
    "program" => "postfix/smtp",
    "message" => "<22>Sep 17 19:12:14 postfix/smtp[18852]: 28D40A036B: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=192.244.100.25[192.244.100.25]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0.09/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9030A15D0)"
}
```

All of the above grok filters are either [common](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) or written by someone else to serve a purpose. Luckily, many people use Postfix, but few have written filters for it, as it is fairly complex.

Once that is established, you can get pretty [crafty](https://github.com/whyscream/postfix-grok-patterns/blob/master/50-filter-postfix.conf) with your Logstash configuration.