# Parsing POSTFIX logs and sending to ElasticSearch

Tags: parsing, logging, fluentd, postfix-mta

I am using Postfix and I need to parse the mail logs after the mails are sent.
Right now, I have been trying to get things to work using Fluentd using the tail plugin to parse Postfix logs.

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot parse them by using the multiline option of the tail plugin. I can parse them individually using regular expressions but not together. This may be because of the fact that the logs are asynchronous in nature and each process logs into the file whenever it has information to be logged. I am planning to write a ruby script for this purpose but this might take a lot of time.

Is there a better solution than writing the script/custom plugin for Fluentd, considering I don't know Ruby/Perl?

**Logs for which I do not care to extract information from:**

```
Jan  5 09:02:48 localhost postfix/pickup[5501]: 1733D16A90A: uid=0 from=&lt;root&gt;
Jan  5 09:02:51 localhost postfix/qmgr[2596]: 1733D16A90A: removed
```

**Logs for which I care to extract information from:**

```
Jan  5 09:02:48 localhost postfix/cleanup[5978]: 1733D16A90A: message-id=&lt;20170105140248.1733D16A90A@mail.testserver.com&gt;
Jan  5 09:02:48 localhost postfix/qmgr[2596]: 1733D16A90A: from=&lt;root@mail.testserver.com&gt;, size=460, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 09:02:51 localhost postfix/smtp[5980]: 1733D16A90A: to=&lt;divij.sehgaal7@gmail.com&gt;, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.130.27]:25, delay=3.4, delays=0.05/0.01/1.9/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1483624971 s11si76004239pgc.259 - gsmtp)
```

The example logs need to be sent to ElasticSearch as a JSON File, which will then save them for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only to track if a mail is sent. You could use Postfix queue id
(1733D16A90A in your log) as index key in elasticsearch. Then you have to parse each line with grok and update the status for your entry.
Take a look at this example for grok patterns :

https://github.com/whyscream/postfix-grok-patterns/blob/master/50-filter-postfix.conf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although, wrote a custom python script that exports the log data to my Elasticsearch index and updates the documents with QueueIDs as keys and data in json as soon as data is found.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42410325/1861357) for parsing Postfix logs with Logstash, and although I hate linking to another answer, the concepts remain the same and should get you started, but do not involve the complexity of the configuration as [whyscream](https://github.com/whyscream/postfix-grok-patterns/blob/master/50-filter-postfix.conf) provided.

The same concepts with grok apply for Fluent as well.

Your best bet is the [file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) input plugin for reading the file. This will ensure that you do not have to worry about multiline processing, and can instead focus on each line of necessary information.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/maillog"
        type => "postfix"   # You can define a type however you like.
    }
}
```

Ultimately you should try to avoid writing a custom script, if possible. The work required to do so has been taken on by the communities of Logstash, Fluent, and other similar tools. Managing regular expressions for thousands of granular logs is an annoyance, at best.

Answer (score 2):

I needed exactly this a few years ago so I wrote [log-ship-elastic-postfix](https://github.com/msimerson/log-ship-elastic-postfix). From my description:

Turns these:

```
Jul 26 04:18:34 mx12 postfix/pickup[20280]: 3mfHGL1r9gzyQP: uid=1208 from=<system>
Jul 26 04:18:34 mx12 postfix/cleanup[20659]: 3mfHGL1r9gzyQP: message-id=<3mfHGL1r9gzyQP@mx15.example.net>
Jul 26 04:18:34 mx12 postfix/qmgr[28761]: 3mfHGL1r9gzyQP: from=<system>, size=813, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 26 04:18:34 mx12 postfix/smtp[20662]: 3mfHGL1r9gzyQP: to=<system>, relay=127.0.0.2[127.0.0.2]:25, delay=0.53, delays=0.13/0/0.23/0.16, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Queued! (#2.0.0))
Jul 26 04:18:34 mx12 postfix/qmgr[28761]: 3mfHGL1r9gzyQP: removed
```

into this:

```js
{
    "id": "3mfHGL1r9gzyQP",
    "host": "mx12",
    "events": [
      {
        "date": "2015-07-26T04:18:34-04:00",
        "action": "queued"
      },
      {
        "to": "system",
        "relay": "127.0.0.2[127.0.0.2]:25",
        "dsn": "2.0.0",
        "status": "sent (250 Queued! (#2.0.0))",
        "date": "2015-07-26T04:18:34-04:00"
      },
      {
        "date": "2015-07-26T04:18:34-04:00",
        "action": "removed"
      }
    ],
    "date": "2015-07-26T04:18:34-04:00",
    "isFinal": true,
    "uid": "1208",
    "message-id": "3mfHGL1r9gzyQP@mx15.example.net",
    "from": "system",
    "size": "813",
    "nrcpt": "1",
    "delay": "0.53",
    "delays": "0.13/0/0.23/0.16"
}
```

It runs under node.js and has billions of postfix log entries passed through it.

Comment: Interesting. This seems to do exactly what I wanted it to do. However, I ended up using Logstash Grok Patterns for this purpose.

Comment: And I actually came across this around the same time as well, but we didn't use it as we wanted to stick to lesser diversity in stack and this ran under node.js

Comment: Is there a HowTo for doing exactly this with logstash patterns? It wasn't even possible back when I tried and I'd love to publish a link to it.

Comment: I won't call it a HowTo, but as far as I remember, I found [this](https://gist.github.com/TinLe/f9763ac68c122cd11b91) link to be useful. Apologies, but I am not sure it is this one, as I switched my job and don't have my previous code/the doc I used to keep those links in, to confirm it.

You might have to do a little R&D of your own on this link(and possibly some others as well) to confirm that this is actually the one.

Comment: That link shows some grok patterns that will parse and index the postfix log entries better, but as near as I can tell, you're still stuck with all the postfix log entries for a particular message spread across a collection of ES docs. That's a much different thing than having them all in a single well formed document.

Comment: Umm, may be that is right! As I said, I do not exactly remember what resources I used. As of now, all I remember is there's a way to do that using logstash grok patterns, just that you'll have to do some R&D of your own. :)